# How do I specify a specific get method using axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am currently working with a yarn React application, and one of my front-end components has a form that sends a get request to the backend.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default function fld(props){
    //set the inital state of the name as null
    const [songName, setSongName] = useState(null);
    //this function is linked to the GET request,
    const handleRetrieve = async (event) =>{
        //prevent the page from reloading
        event.preventDefault();
        //set the formData
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("songName", songName)
        try{
            const response = await axios({
                method: "get",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/",
                data: formData
            });
            console.log(response)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    };
    const handleNameSelect = (event ) =>{
        setSongName(event.target.name[0]);
    };

    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleRetrieve}>
            <label>List out the songs</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleNameSelect}/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

The thing is, I have multiple get requests in the backend, but only want to fire off the second one.
FIRST GET REQUEST:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

SECOND GET REQUEST (the one I want to fire)

```
app.get("/Uploadedfiles/:name", (req, res) => {
  console.log("GET method: Uploadedfiles/:name")
  const params = req.params.name;
  let red = read(params);
  console.log("reading from folder");
  res.send(red);
});
```

help pls :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is to add the endpoint path to the config object in axios like this:

```
const response = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/Uploadedfiles/${songName}`,
  });
```

Another way to use axios is to use the implicit methods like this:

```
const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/Uploadedfiles/${songName}`);
```

For a complete list of examples on different ways to use axios here is their official docs [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/example)